# Lazy evaluation of linq expressions

Tags: lambda, lazy-evaluation

Im trying to build a expression evaluator with
Linq expressions. Im trying to make It so that
all function arguments are lazy evaluated but can't quite
get there.

I'm writing in psuedo here but the real thing is
linq expressions.

Example expression:

```
Func1(Func2(10) + 1, Func3(10))
```

**Update**

```
Expression.Call(Func1,
    Expression.Add(
        Expression.Call(Func2, Expression.Constant(10)),
        Expression.Constant(1))
    Expression.Call(Func3, Expression.Constant(10))
)
```

I want the arguments to Func1 to be evaluated at invoke-time
that is I want the arguments to be lazy evaluated. It's doable when wrapping the
argument expressions inside a lambda expression but if I do that the binary expression
Func2(10) + 1 will fail because one can't add a lambda to a constant expression.

The actual function code will look like this:

```
  int Func1(Func<int> arg1, Func<int> arg2)
  {
  }
```

arg1 when run will evaluate "Func2(10) + 1"
arg2 when run will evaluate "Func3(10)"

So here I can choose if I want to evalute the argument or not, to get the lazy effect.

Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: I think real expression-tree code will be an improvement for us over your pseudo-code.

Comment: @Kirk: Ok, i'll edit my post.

Comment: thanks for the edit.  But I'm confused why you think this isn't *already* being lazily evaluated?  The expression `Func2(10) + 1` won't be evaluated until `Func1` is invoked.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Kirk: But thats the thing, when Func1 is invoked all arguments will be evaluated, I don't want that to happen. I want as you can see in my code choose which and when of the arguments to be invoked/evaluated, that why I have     Func<int> arg1 instead of     int arg1.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand.  I will post an answer so that I can write out some formatted code, we can continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin, I think it would be helpful to first discuss the problem without the use of expression trees.  You said that this is the function you want to call:

```cs
int Func1(Func<int> arg1, Func<int> arg2)
{
}
```

And you want to figure out how to implement the following using expression trees?

```
Func1(() => Func2(10) + 1, () => Func3(10));
```

Is this correct so far?  If that is all true, then consider this class:

```cs
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Func1(() => Func2(10) + 1, () => Func3(10)));            

        var arg1 = Expression.Add(Expression.Call(typeof(Program), "Func2", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(10)), Expression.Constant(1));
        var arg2 = Expression.Call(typeof(Program), "Func3", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Constant(10));
        var callFunc1 = Expression.Call(typeof(Program), "Func1", Type.EmptyTypes, Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(arg1), Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(arg2));
        var tester = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(callFunc1);
        int result = tester.Compile()();

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    static int Func1(Func<int> arg1, Func<int> arg2)
    {
        return arg1() + arg2();
    }

    static int Func2(int arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    static int Func3(int arg)
    {
        return 2 * arg;
    }
}
```

It will print out `31` both times: `(10 + 1) + (10 * 2)`.  The first is invoking it directly, the second using expression trees.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. I want all of my functions to act this way.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting, will look at it more tomorrow.

Comment: Expression trees are immutable. So the next step would be to create an expression tree visitor that copies any non-function-call nodes into a new tree, and converts any function-call nodes into calls to lambda expressions which invoke those function-call nodes. Right?